# Book suggestion: Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, book-recommendation

Could someone please suggest a good enough book for linear algebra, that can help me with quantum chemistry?
Thank you!

Comment: You probably need something that more generally deals with normed linear spaces, and not just linear algebra, but also not a functional analysis text, which usually requires a rather sophisticated background in mathematics. Maybe [**Mathematics for Quantum Chemistry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0486442306) by Anderson. Also, consider getting Levine's [**Quantum Chemistry**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0321803450) (maybe from library; any edition), because it is excellent in providing all the needed post-calculus/ODE background in a manner suitable for its intended audience, **(continued)**

Comment: at least the 1974 2nd edition I used 40 years ago did. And maybe also useful would be [**Problems and Solutions in Quantum Chemistry and Physics**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/B00A4208ME), which was a supplementary text when I took the class (one of the authors was my instructor).

Comment: *more generally deals with* --- Since normed spaces are more specialized than vector spaces, I probably should have written "additionally deals with".

Comment: I am sorry, I accidentally  clicked on 'Flag' . Your suggestions were helpful. I was trying to click on "upvote"!

Comment: Yes, I am looking for a general book on algebra for Q.M., But, I have very little background in Mathematics, It is difficult to follow concepts in Stat. Mech., Q.M. etc.

Comment: *Linear Algebra Done Right* by S. Axler

Answer (score 3):

I don’t quite now how much “Linear Algebra” you will gonna need, but I will give a list of some books so you can take a look and see what’s the most suitable for you.

Some books for Linear Algebra that I thing they are really good are

- *Linear Algebra*, by Hoffman K. and Kuntze R. (which goes a little in depth but it is a great piece)
- *Basic Linear Algebra*, by Blyth T. S. and Robertson E. F. (this one gives you the fundamentals in a more readable way)
- *Linear Algebra*, by Lang S. (in the same level as the previous one)
- *Linear Algebra and Its Applications*, by Strang G. (which is really directed through applications of Linear Algebra, therefore it could be of very interest for you)
- *Elementary Linear Algebra*, by Anton H. (which presents the fundamentals in a very “easy to follow” way)

Also, always check the bibliography of each book because it can contain some good books there as well.

Comment: Thank you, it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

My former advisor Peter Petersen has a book, Lang has one, my undergraduate professor Bill Jacob has one, there is one by Howard Anton, Gilbert Strang has more than one I believe, and there are more...

I got a tip from a user who is into Linear Algebra that Mac Duffee's book on Vectors and Matrices is really good.